# array_unique for rearranged values

Tags: php

This is my array

```
$input = array("ASTY","PLO","KNGO","c","LOP","OPL","HONGO","TSAY");
```

here,

ASTY,TSAY  = contains same letters. I need to keep first one.

PLO,LOP,OPL= contains same letters. I need to keep first one.

So, my desired output array

```
$output = array("ASTY","PLO","KNGO","c","HONGO");
```

Is there any builtin function to do this?
array_unique works fine for non-rearranged word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To compare whether any two values are equal in this scenario, you would simply *order* the letters and compare the ordered value. To *deduplicate* the array, use the fact that arrays keys are unique:

```
$unique = [];
foreach ($input as $word) {
    $key = str_split($word);
    sort($key);
    $unique[join($key)] = $word;
}

// optionally:
$unique = array_values($unique);
```

Comment: Superb! Thank you very much.

Comment: This would actually return the last occurrence of all same-combination strings; it would return "TSAY" and "OPL" in the above example, while the OP wanted to keep the first occurrence. You might want to use `array_key_exists` before assigning it to `$unique`.

Comment: @Irvin If this really matters, the fix is trivial... :)